# How to read n integers from standard input in C++?

Tags: c++, stdin

I need to read something like:

```
5 60 35 42
2 38 6
5 8
300 1500 900
```

And then save the first line in an array. After calling other functions do the same with the next line, and so on.

I try with `gets()` and then use `sscanf()` to scan the integers from the string, but I don't know how to read n numbers from a string.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619227/best-way-to-get-ints-from-a-string-with-whitespace or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195823/reading-unknown-number-of-integers-from-stdin-c

Comment: C++ would be best but it would be nice to know how in both.

Comment: @RobertoLapuente if you want to know the answer for C, it's best to ask another question (well, search first, I'm sure it has been answered before). *A good answer for each language will be completely different*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've seen input files like this for competitions before.  If speed is more of an issue than error detection, you could use a custom routine.  Here's one similar to that I use:

```
void readintline(unsigned int* array, int* size) {
    char buffer[101];
    size=0;
    char* in=buffer;
    unsigned int* out=array;
    fgets(buffer, 100, stdin);
    do {
        *out=0;
        while(*in>='0') {
            *out= *out* 10 + *in-'0';
            ++in;
        }
        if (*in)
            ++in; //skip whitespace
        ++out;
    } while(*in);
    size = out-array;
}
```

It will destroy your memory if there's more than 100 characters on a line, or more numbers than array can hold, but you won't get a faster routine to read in lines of unsigned ints.

On the other hand, if you want simple:

```
int main() {
    std::string tmp;
    while(std::getline(std::cin, tmp)) {
        std::vector<int> nums;
        std::stringstream ss(tmp);
        int ti;
        while(ss >> ti) 
            nums.push_back(ti);
        //do stuff with nums
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually the input is from an ACM programming competition. I have thought of something like this but I think there should be an easier way.

Answer (score 36):

## C++

If you have an unknown number of entries spread across an unknown number of lines, ending at EOF:

```
int n;
while(cin >> n)
  vector_of_int.push_back(n);
```

If you have a known number of entries spread across an unknown number of lines:

```
int n;
int number_of_entries = 20; // 20 for example, I don't know how many you have.
for(int i ; i < number_of_entries; ++i)
  if(cin >> n)
    vector_of_int.push_back(n);
```

If you have an uknown number of entries on a single line:

```
std::string str;
std::getline(std::cin, str);
std::istringstream sstr(str);
int n;
while(sstr >> n)
  vector_of_int.push_back(n);
```

If you have a unknown number of entries spread across a known number of lines:

```
for(int i = 0; i < number_of_lines; ++i) {
  std::string str;
  if(std::getline(std::cin, str)) {
    std::istringstream sstr(str);
    int n;
    while(sstr >> n)
      vector_of_int.push_back(n);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this one line at a time? Because I think cin won't read the \n so I won't know when the line changes.

Comment: @RobertoLapuente -  The first way that I have is correct for for the example you gave -- several numbers spread over several lines, ending at the end of the file. `cin` **will** read and ignore the `\n`, just as it reads and ignores the space characters.

Comment: @Rob: I think each line is it's own array.  He needs to run a function on each of the four arrays.

Comment: @Rob I can just do 'while (std::getline(std::cin, str)>0)' or something like that? what does 'getline' return value is when it reaches EOF?

Comment: @Roberto : For your purposes it returns `false` (not technically the case, but again, for _your_ purposes...), so `while (std::getline(std::cin, str))` is sufficient.

Comment: @MooingDuck - right, the last example is known number of lines, unknown number of entries.  Or do I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: @Rob: completely misread the "title" of the last one.  My bad.

Comment: @MooingDuck - and I just realized that I missed the fundamental requirement of the original question (read data per line). Your answer beats mine.

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably write the code something like this:

```
// Warning: untested code.
std::vector<int> read_line_ints(std::istream &is) { 
    std::string temp;
    std::getline(is, temp);

    std::istringstream buffer(temp);
    int num;
    std::vector<int> ret;

    while (buffer>>num)
        ret.push_back(num);
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In C++, you can use `std::istringstream`.

```
std::string nums = "1 20 300 4000";
std::istringstream stream(nums);
int a, b, c, d;
stream >> a >> b >> c >> d;
assert(a == 1 && b == 20 && c == 300 && d == 4000);
```

If you want to get it from the standard input, then do the same, but just use `std::cin`

```
std::cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
```

Answer (score 3):

C++:

```
vector<int> ints;
while( !cin.eof() )
{
   int t;
   cin >> t;
   if ( !cin.eof() )
      ints.push_back(t);
}
```

Alternative (thx to Shahbaz)

```
int t;
vector<int> ints;
while(cin >> t)
   ints.push_back(t);
```

Comment: Because the `eof` flag doesn't get set until _after_ one attempts to read past the end, so the last element in `ints` will always be garbage data.

Comment: Please don't encourage the use of `eof()`. It doesn't do what people think, and it almost always results in a bug (like the one you have here).

Comment: The use of eof (in general) has no problem. I fixed the code.

Comment: Is there a way to do this one line at a time? Because I think cin won't read the \n so I won't know when the line changes.

Comment: @George : No you didn't -- `while( !somestream.eof() )` is never correct, and in this case the last element of each `temp` instance will contain garbage data, as well as all the contents of the last element of `ints`.

Comment: If you don't believe that `eof()` is evil, consider [this program](http://ideone.com/MD3ZM).

Comment: @Rob I can't replicate the problem. When I try it, it prints 3 numbers.

Comment: You placed an end-of-line before the end-of-file. Your loop gives different answers according to whether the final EOL is present or absent (in ideone it was absent). Additionally, your loop gives an infinite loop if there is any non-numeric data in the input.

Comment: @Rob All common editors I have in mind, put the extra \n at the end of the file. Also in terminal you have to be in an empty new line to give the EOF signal. Additionally the op didn't ask for error handling.

Answer (score 3):

The quick solution is to read them with [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html)

```
int array[1000];
int index = 0;

while ((index < 1000) && (scanf("%d", &tmp) == 1)) {
    array[index++] = tmp;
}
```

This still needs a bit more validation ...

Comment: Don't forget the space before `%d` to eat any whitespace.

Comment: @RobertoLapuente I would go with this solution too. Many people don't know the usage of return value of `scanf`, so even if you decided to go with c++'s `istringstream`, make sure you learn this point.

Comment: @TomZych It is automatically done. The problem with space before `%d` is that if before the first integer there is no space, then `scanf` fails (because you told it that it **must** see whitespace)

Comment: @Shahbaz: Good point. I don't use `scanf`, too fragile, I was remembering something from my C course back in '91. I guess you put the space after instead? I'm pretty sure you need it.

Comment: @TomZych, then you would force `scanf` to read space after the last number which may not be existent. In general `scanf` ignores whitespace before and after your format string **unless** you are requesting `%c` which reads space as a character also and doesn't ignore it. In that case, yes you need space.

Comment: Is there a way to do this one line at a time? Because I think cin won't read the \n so I won't know when the line changes.

Comment: I answered with C in mind. I "have no idea" what `cin` is :-)

Comment: @pmg: `cin` is the "C++ version" of `stdin`.  Basically, your code ignores the newline characters.

Comment: @Shanbaz: <quote>White space (such as blanks, tabs, or newlines) in the format string match any amount of white space, including none, in the input.</quote>.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ it's extremely simple to read N integers separated by whitespace via stdin:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const unsigned N = 5;

int main(void)
{
   int nums[N];

   for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i)
      cin >> nums[i];

   cout << "Your numbers were:\n";

   for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i)
      cout << nums[i] << " ";

   cout << "\n";

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I took to long to post because I couldn't see the code button. :/
Also I used an array rather than a vector since we already know the size of the array, hope Stroustrup won't mind.

Note also, no error handling in this code.